# Событие onMouseOut не должно вызываться на потомках

Tags: javascript, html

Есть вот такая страница

```
 <div id="parent" style='border: 3px solid red; padding:4px;'>
 <form action="forms_done.html" method=post>
 <table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=2 border=0 id=tbl>
 <tr><td><input type=text id="t[0][0]" name="t[0][0]" size=4></td></tr>
 </table>
 <br>
 <input type="submit" name="btnOk" onClick="return SubmitAll()">&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <input type="button" name="addrow" onClick="AddRow()" value="Добавить строку">&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <input type="button" name="addcol" onClick="AddCol()" value="Добавить столбец">&nbsp;&nbsp;
 </form>
 </div>
```

и скрипт с событием mouseout:

```
function onMouseOut(event) {
    e = event.toElement || event.relatedTarget;
if (e.parentNode == this || e.parentNode.parentNode == this ||    e.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode == this ||
                       e == this) {
    return;
}
alert('MouseOut');
// handle mouse event here!
```

};

```
document.getElementById("parent").addEventListener('mouseout',onMouseOut,true);
```

Мне необходимо сделать так, чтобы input при наведении на него указателя мыши не вызывал события onMouseOut элемента div. Добавление в условие четверного parentNode результата не даёт.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** изначально напутал с направлением распространения событий. В вашем случае только так:

```
function onMouseOut(event) {
    var event = event || window.event; // cross-browser event
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
    if (target.id === this.id) {
        alert('MouseOut');
        // handle mouse event here!
    }
    return;        
}
```

**[Посмотреть пример](http://jsfiddle.net/KcpLn/1/)** (зеленая область - div#parent)

Comment: Вызывается же всё равно событие div'а, а не событие детей. Поэтому stopPropagation() тут не поможет.